# How to get VS Code to take input while debugging C code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I try to debug with input for a C program, I cannot input a value. The terminal doesn't seem to execute. I've been having this problem for a while and all the solution in the internet doesn't seem to apply. I've tried resetting my VS Code settings and re-download it, but I still run into the same problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char name[5];
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

How it looks when I start debugging:

[image: How it looks when I start debugging]

My launch.json file:

[image: My launch.json file]

Extensions I've downloaded, or that came by default:
[image]

Comment: 1) what extension are you using to get the `lldb` launch config type? 2) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: Have ou Have you tried checking the **DEBUG CONSOLE** tab?

Comment: The only debug related thing I have downloaded in my extension is "CodeLLDB" by Vadim Chugunov. the Debug Console doesn't show anything... When I click next, it shows "name: " but I cannot input anything.